# How to get list of +1000 urls from google search?

Tags: google-search

I am looking to download a list of urls from Google search results. Basically I have a search query 'site:www.mywebsite.com' which is returning 6,500 results. I need the url to all these results. I know there are a number of ways to get the first 1,000 (and this is google's limit), but I need all 6,500 results.

Is there a way to do this and if so, how? Can it be done through Google's CustomSearch API?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.